# Given lots of intervals of login and logout of users, find maximum rush happened

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given lots of intervals of login and logout of users, find maximum rush happened.
example:

login: [1,5,5]

logout: [5,10,5]

maximum rush happened at 5 and it happened thrice. So answer is 3

login: [4,10]

logout: [8,20]

maximum rush is 1 in those two interval. Hence answer is 16 = 8-4+1 + 20-10+1

In simple terms maxRush*(length of final intervals which might or might not overlap)

Needs to be done in O(nlogn) to pass all test case.

Stackoverflow contains multiple same questions but not exact and the result it want here is totally different from intersecting intervals.

Comment: Please quote the original description of this challenge and provide a link if there is one. The concept of rush is not well explained in your post. Also provide some non-trivial testcases and what is expected as output for them. Finally, add the constraints: range of the input, time limits, programming language, ...

Comment: Why are the lengths of the intervals not used in the first example? If I follow the formula that you have used in the second example, I would get 12 = 5-1+1 + 10-5+1 + 5-5+1. Why is it 3? Also, what if input is `login: [1, 1, 5]` and `logout: [2, 6, 6]`? What is the answer then? Does the length of the interval (1, 6) count twice (once for each "rush") or just once?

Comment: @trincot there's no link. Concept of rush is basically if you draw intervals on x axis then the max number of intersection(if any) else check 2nd test case.
There were only 2 test cases were provided in the question. 

Also please don't use the formula that i've provided, it's just for understanding purpose.

1-2
1------6
------56
if you check your test case, the answer is 2. [1,2] happened twice that's the most intersecting interval hence the frequency of most intersecting interval is the answer.

Comment: Well, then I don't understand the question and why the reasoning is different in the first example compared to the second example.  Also, why do you say `[1,2]` happens twice, and is the "most intersection interval" -- there is also `[5,6]`. Not clear at all what the code challenge is asking here. Please provide the *literal* text of the assignment you got.

Comment: @trincot [5,6] happened only once. 1,2 intersected twice which is the maximum intersection. Hence 2 is the answer. If twice intersection happened in other interval then we wouls need to add them.

Comment: I don't get it. `[5,6]` overlaps with `[1,6]`. Why do you label that as "happened only once". The same is true for `[1,2]` which overlaps with `[1,6]`. Please (!) include the original description of the code challenge.

Comment: Yes we should include [5,6] also. And I'm saying it again(!) original description is not present as it was in the OA of some company and i don't have screenshot of that. These 2 examples were provided which I've mentioned and it could be done with sweep line in O(nlogn) but i'm not sure how.

Comment: Ok then I will move on. The rules are not clear to me. Good luck.

Comment: When responding to a comment requesting clarification it's best to edit your question rather than replying with a comment. Questions should be self-contained as readers should not be required to read comments to understand it.